# Store user input in array

Tags: java, arrays

Hello all I am in need of some help with getting a users input with double[] getUserInput().

I know how to get a users input and storing it, but I do not know how to do it with a array and I have to use double[] getUserInput(). Can someone explain to me how to set this particular code up "**double[] getUserInput()**", and what it does?

I'm supposed to Store the user provided values into an array of doubles, and return this array to the main method.

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: a) What language are you doing this in? b) Have a look at the first sample program `ArrayDemo` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) to see how you can assign values to array elements. You might not be using Java but it's usually the same in other languages. Maybe.

Comment: Sorry I'm working with JAva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code to return double array

```
    public double[] getUserInput(){
       double[] userinput = {/*double values separated by comma*/};
       return userinput;
    }
```